# Webbrowser only download pdf and skip everything else

Tags: c#, asp.net

Someone made a c# program that cycles through a set of links till it can find something to download, this can be a word document or a pdf, we would only like to have the pdf files and skip all the other files! The server is asp based so it does not show pdf in it's url! the source code of the page does show this however:

```
type="application/pdf"
```

the type is placed in an embed.
How could we stop the browser from downloading word documents, ... and only download the pdf's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a web request and set

```
webRequest.Method = "HEAD";
```

That will download just the headers, which you can then inspect to see if the MIME type is one that you want to download.